# Can't Save Omni-Channel flow due to conflicting errors. An error is thrown if recordId is included, and if it is not included

Tags: visual-workflow, omnichannel

I'm trying to update a case record coming in from email-to-case via an omni-channel flow. This is so I can set fields on the case, dependant on what email was used to generate the case (as there are multiple emails generating cases with the same record type, origin and priority).

I've tried creating an omni-channel flow for this, as these can be assigned to each email-to-case address, but when I try to save the flow I either get the error:
"You must include a recordId Variable for flows of type RoutingFlow"
or, if I include a recordId variable, I get the error:
"The recordId Variable is invalid for use in flows of type RoutingFlow".

The flow is simply assigning a static value to a field on the case (input_record).

Am I missing something here? The errors seem to contradict themselves? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't resolved this yet - what solved it for me was creating the variable as a text variable and **marking it as available for input**. Once done, the flow was okay to save.